# React (NextJS) component not playing transition animation on first render

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-transitions

I have a simple functional component using modules pattern to apply styles.
Component receives a number (targetView) as prop indicating that which view number is for displaying this component. I use Zustand store to keep track which view currently user is viewing.

When this component gets rendered, useEffect is ran to check if view === targetView and toggle loaded variable to either true or false. Ternary operator is used to apply or remove additional className from element to trigger transition.

Transition is simple, element starts with transform:translate(-100%) and additional class sets this to 0, transform:translate(0). So element slides into view or out of view depending on is user currently viewing this component.

This is basically working like I thought it would, only problem is that when component gets mounted there is no initial transition. Title element just appears in final position.

I can inspect element, and then toggle on / off additional class and transition works, in and out. What is wrong here ? I think there is some quirk with either React or NextJS that I'm not aware of. I first thought that maybe StrictMode (using react 18+) running useEffect twice might be cause but I tried turning it off and issue remained

EDIT: [Code repository](https://github.com/Ettur/issue)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./FX.module.scss";
import { useStore } from "../../store";

interface FXProps {
  targetView: number;
}

const FX = ({ targetView }: FXProps): JSX.Element => {
  const view = useStore((state) => state.view);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    view === targetView ? setLoaded((p) => true) : setLoaded((p) => false);
  }, [targetView, view]);

  return (
    <div className={styles["FX-container"]}>
      <div className={styles["FX-text-container"]}>
        <h1
          className={`${styles["FX-text-title"]} ${
            loaded ? styles["translate-x-0"] : ""
          }`}
        >
          FX.
        </h1>            
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FX;
```

Css classes are

```
.FX-text-title {
    font-family: "Inter Tight", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: clamp(68px, 8vw, 80px);
    transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.translate-x-0 {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

EDIT: As a bit of a hack / alaternative it does work when I add animation to translate-x-0. Still dont know why its not working with just transition.

```
.translate-x-0 {
    animation: anim 0.5s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes anim {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the behaviour the same on all browsers? have you tried something like: `.translate-x-0 {
    transform: translateX(-100%) translateX(0);
}`? Looks like the browser omits the interpolation for some reason which could be fixed by tweaking the way you apply and overwrite the `translateX` properties. I think it's hard to help without a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Ill see if I can create a CodePen, but I tried to write 
transform: translateX(-100%) translateX(0);
then it didnt turn up at all, stayed at -100%. Only tried on latest chrome

Comment: the transition value is defined in FX-text-title which is rendered separately from translate-x-0. When the component first loads, it will render the component with the fx-text-title applied. Then, the useEffect runs and changes loading to true which applies the transform but the transition has already happened. Try moving the transition to translate-x-0 and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, I'd push this up to a public repo on github rather than use a google drive link.

Comment: the transition value is defined in FX-text-title which is rendered separately from translate-x-0. When the component first loads, it will render the component with the fx-text-title applied. Then, the useEffect runs and changes loading to true which applies the transform but the transition has already happened. Try moving the transition to translate-x-0 and see if that helps.

Comment: @KylePendergast tried to switch transition to translate-x-0, issue remained.
Ill try to push it to repo

Comment: @KylePendergast created public repo
https://github.com/Ettur/issue

Comment: I does work when I add animation to translate-x-0, still no idea why it doesnt work with transition